# Add 2 string arrays to 2 columns of ListView

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, winforms, listview

i m trying to add to array of string in my listview i can add one array with

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(string1 .Select(Function(x) New ListViewItem(x)) _
                              .ToArray)
```

but how to add the second as `subitem` in the second column 
to make them facing each other

i also tried

```
For Each s As String In  string1
    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    livv.Items.Add(t)
    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
    For Each t As String In  string2
        Dim item2 As New ListViewItem
        item2.SubItems.Add(t)
        ListView1.Items.Add(item2)
   Next
next
```

but it didn't work. How do I add the two array of string to my listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the arrays are the same size you can use a For n Loop:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem
For n As Int32 = 0 To string1.Length - 1
    ' create new LVI with data from string1
    lvi = New ListViewItem(string1(n))
    ' add corresponding string2 element as the only subitem
    lvi.SubItems.Add(string2(n))
    ' add LVI to listview
    myLV.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

If there are not an equal number of elements, you will have to add a test and respond accordingly.

Comment: yes they are the same size and it work 
thank you so match you just save my day